# Create an extra column based condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Tenancy_ID         Start_Date                  Cancelled_Date
1                  2011-10-02 07:18:16         2011-12-02 08:15:16
2                  2012-10-22 07:18:17         NaT
1                  2013-06-02 07:14:12         NaT
3                  2016-10-02 07:18:16         2017-03-02 08:18:15
```

From the above I would like to create new column named as Cancelled_Status based on the availability of cancelled date in Cancelled_Date.

Expected Output:

```
Tenancy_ID         Start_Date                  Cancelled_Date            Cancelled_status
1                  2011-10-02 07:18:16         2011-12-02 08:15:16       Cancelled
2                  2012-10-22 07:18:17         NaT                       Not_Cancelled
1                  2013-06-02 07:14:12         NaT                       Not_Cancelled
3                  2016-10-02 07:18:16         2017-03-02 08:18:15       Cancelled
```

Comment: have you  tried numpy where? it looks relatively easy with numpy where

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df['Cancelled_status'] = np.where(df['Cancelled_Date'].isna(), 'Not_Cancelled', 'Cancelled')
```

Alternative with 
[`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df['Cancelled_status'] = np.where(df['Cancelled_Date'].notna(), 'Cancelled', 'Not_Cancelled')
```